# How to disable compiler optimization for Ceph?

Tags: gdb, ceph

I am building Ceph from source v12.2.4 using the steps mentioned in 
https://github.com/ceph/ceph/tree/v12.2.4 -- README.md

```
git clone git://github.com/ceph/ceph
cd ceph
git checkout v12.2.4
./install-deps.sh
./do_cmake.sh
cd build
make
ctest
```

on debugging test: unittest_bloom_filter, gdb shows *optimized out* for few variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for debug builds, like a std. cmake project `cd build && cmake  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` should help. `cmake -LH ..` should show the current settings (default is RelWithDebugInfo)